# Как оставить скрол во внутренних элементах при отключении его в плагине fullpage?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, fullpage

Вся страница сделана на плагине [fullpage](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js). На странице есть модальные окна внутри есть блоки со скролом. И вот при открытии модального окна я соответственно блокирую скрол страницы методом `setAllowScrolling()`, но с ним вообще отключается скрол на мышке какой либо, можно ли как то обойти этот момент?

ps пробовал вызывать метод `destroy('all')`, но как и следовало ожидать все сбразывается и страница скролится в самое начало

```js
const myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {});

$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    myFullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);
  }, 10);
});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
  myFullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
});
```

```css
.section {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 3em;
}

p {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/dist/fullpage.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Запустить модальное окно
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">Two 1</div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
        Запустить модальное окно
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Libero, maiores! Quod eligendi distinctio, corporis dignissimos doloribus qui neque ipsum non magni, adipisci suscipit ullam sapiente facere odit? Atque, praesentium necessitatibus?
    Quam tenetur eaque, deserunt accusamus labore sunt ab! Provident tempora veritatis facere quibusdam ea a nam accusamus voluptas? Accusantium id ipsa omnis accusamus ab aliquid perspiciatis recusandae ipsum corporis dolor.
    Distinctio fugit esse enim hic consectetur fuga et perspiciatis corrupti tempora dolore nam officia nihil saepe quibusdam illum vero, sequi autem accusantium aliquid voluptatem iusto possimus minima iste architecto? Fugit.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из документации использовал свойство `normalScrollElements`

```
const myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    normalScrollElements: '.modal',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте bind и unbind методы или event preventdefault и stopPropagation для блокировки и разблокировании нужного элемента.

Наверное в вашем фреймворке используется подобные методы.
Можно отключить скролл в элементе body а потом восстановить или добавить исключение для элемента через overflow

Также можно добавить overflow hidden для модального окна

```
    $("#Modal").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

или
     $('body').bind('scroll', function(e){e.preventDefault()})
     $('body').unbind('scroll')

Все таки пошел на сайт фреймворка.
Попробовал первые два способа которые должны решить проблему.
normalScrollElements и fixedElements
Последний как по мне решил задачу:Он указывает что остается закрепленным.

После нескольких попыток  решить разными способами, например указать позицию окна в нуль, пошел читать мануал оставалось пару сложных и неправильных методов и частично решающие задачу способа нативным js.  Так что в дам случае гораздо проще решить проблему средствами самого фреймворка. Новое решение:

https://jsfiddle.net/reu5jft7/1/

```
     const myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
     fixedElements: 'body',
 });

 $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', () => {
   setTimeout(() => {

   }, 10);
 });

 $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
   myFullpage.setAllowScrolling(true);
 });
```

Comment: Не помогло, возможно конечно я что-то делаю не так. Если не затруднит сделайте пример где у вас работает данный подход. Пока что ваш пример с ошибками.

Comment: Нашел решение средствами fullpage,добавил пример,подробности выше.

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш пример, он вообще убирает скрол fullpage когда он нужен. Но ваш ответ мне помог - нужно не второй а первый ваш параметр указать`normalScrollElements: '.modal'` и все работает. Можете немного изменить ответ и вам поставлю как решенный